# How parse SOAP with JDOM

Tags: java, soap, jdom

I am have following SOAP example message:

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
     xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
     <SOAP-ENV:Body>
     <CREATE__CompIntfc__SUPPORT_DOC_TBL>
        <SUPPORT_DOC_ID>POLICE</SUPPORT_DOC_ID>
        <SUPPORT_DOC>
            <DESCR>Police Report</DESCR>
            <DESCRSHORT>Police</DESCRSHORT>
        </SUPPORT_DOC>
    </CREATE__CompIntfc__SUPPORT_DOC_TBL>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
 </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

and i need parse  element. I am writig following code for this task but's its not working:

```
                  File inputXML=new                 File("/home/igor/IdeaProjects/jdomtest/src/main/resources/example.xsd");
    SAXBuilder saxBuilder=new SAXBuilder();
    try{
        Document rootElement=saxBuilder.build(inputXML);
        Element element=rootElement.getRootElement();

    Namespace ns=Namespace.getNamespace()
      List<Element> list=element.getChildren("Body");
 System.out.print(list.size());

  for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
  Element el = (Element)list.get(i);
    System.out.println(el);
   }

    }catch (Exception exp){
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But it's not any wirting on screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Body element is in the `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/` namespace, but you're using the single argument `getChildren` method which looks for elements in *no* namespace. You need to pass an appropriate `Namespace` to the two-argument version of `getChildren`.